# Can't .map() a value that seems to be Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

When i console log the variable "pokemons" separately, it does return an array. But when i try to map it, i get an error : TypeError: pokemons.map is not a function

my code :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import PokeList from "./components/PokeList";
import Paginator from "./components/Paginator";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  let [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
  let [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    () =>
      setPokemons(
        axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon").then((res) => {
          setPokemons(res.data.results.map((poki) => poki.name));
        })
      ),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PokeList pokemons={pokemons}></PokeList> <Paginator></Paginator>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and the map is called in PokeList component :

```
import React from "react";

const PokeList = ({ pokemons }) => {
  console.log(pokemons.map((poki) => "Yellow"));
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Here are all your pokis: </h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PokeList;
```

Comment: I don't think you should be wrapping `setPokemons` around your `axios` call

Comment: Can you add another console.log before the map and just output pokemons to see what you have?

Comment: Previously, it logged normal array as it should, but now it logs this :[]
and Promise {<pending>}

Comment: Now i removed outer setPokemons() and added the one inside axios call. now it console logs this : (20) ["bulbasaur", "ivysaur", "venusaur", "charmander", "charmeleon", "charizard", "squirtle", "wartortle", "blastoise", "caterpie", "metapod", "butterfree", "weedle", "kakuna", "beedrill", "pidgey", "pidgeotto", "pidgeot", "rattata", "raticate"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `map()` was failing is because axios was returning the promise for the first couple of calls. So your child component was attempting to map over a promise, which it of course could not do. Another way around this issue is to check for length of the array and only map if there is length.

```
    if(pokemons.length){
     pokemons.map((poke) => {
      console.log(poke)
     })
    }
```

Here's a link to show it working: https://codesandbox.io/s/tempsandbox-okypp

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrapped the whole `axios promise object` into setPokemans :

Try below :

[image: Edit affectionate-hypatia-o6st5]

The following code returns a promise object, not an array!

```
axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon").then((res) => {
   setPokemons(res.data.results.map((poki) => poki.name));
}) // returns object
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to this :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import PokeList from "./components/PokeList";
import Paginator from "./components/Paginator";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  let [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
  let [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    () =>
      axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon").then((res) => {
        /* setStatus(true);
          console.log(status); */
        setPokemons(res.data.results.map((poki) => poki.name));
      }),
    []
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PokeList pokemons={pokemons} status={status}></PokeList>{" "}
      <Paginator></Paginator>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and now map is working.can someone explain why? The only visible change i made was to remove setPokemons() around axios call, which was there by mistake. Could that be reason why i was getting weird pokemons variable?

Comment: `axios.get` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), not an array.